# Should a comma be added and is the sentence right?

Tags: sentence-construction, commas, as

In the sentence:

> I would like to come to the UK this summer to improve my English as much as possible as I am going to study English at university next year.

Is it Okay to use "as" three times consequently like this? and are there any commas that should be added?

Comment: @Andrew - You are correct, but it might also be worth mentioning that if we strike the third _as_ and replace it with a comma, it's suddently a complete and grammatical sentence: _To improve my English as much as possible, I am going to study English at university next year_.

Comment: Now it's a complete sentence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely put a comma after the word possible to indicate a break in sentence structure. As for the repeated use of the word as, it is perfectly acceptable in this circumstance. "as much as possible" is a widely used phrase. If you want to, you can change the last as to "because" to use more word variety while still keeping the meaning intact.

Comment: I love the idea to use "because" instead of a third "as", but I'm not sold on the assertion that a comma is necessary. I'd probably not use one.